# How to add RSS to a community page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, rss, community

I have a website with a RSS (fixed, I had written "CSS" instead) that I would like to post regularly to a Facebook community. Whereas there are lots of tutorials for doing that in a personal Facebook page, I cannot find a solution for adding RSS to a community page (poorer in terms of admin options and settings). I would like to have the Facebook community constantly and automatically updated with RSS from my website. Is it possible to do? In case so, do you know the steps to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [Social RSS application](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=23798139265) to your Facebook page. To get started look at the help from [Facebook about adding apps](http://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=add%20app%20to%20facebook%20page). Once you've added it follow the instructions in the app.